# Teaching entity framework generating SQL for custom NodeTypes

Tags: entity-framework, expression-trees

Is it possible to customize generation of SQL by using custom Expression inheritors with NodeType Extension and CanReduce = false?

Consider the following gist where Name is a property in the ViewModel and Attribute1 is an attribute in SQL-typed column in MS SQL.

```
/* may not compile, focus is on SQL generation. */
Expression<Func<ViewModel, bool>> expr = (vm) => vm.Name == "abc" && vm.Attribute1 == 123;
var translator = new CustomExpressionVisitor();
LambdaExpression translated = (LambdaExpression)translator.Visit(expr);

/*
translated has a custom Expression type for vm.Attribute1 == 123 part, it is of type XmlPredicateExpression and this expression has all necessary information to generate an SQL query on this column.
*/
```

How can we teach EntityFramework to generate SQL for this expression? Is it possible?